# Como emitir factura a una persona natural o jurídica

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola amigos sigo aquí tratando de avanzar en esto de base de datos y me encuentro ahora con una nueva inquietud, pues resulta que decidí ampliar a mi base de datos de compras con una cuenta,  pues nada busque en la red algo similar pero no encuentro algo que me ayude a resolver este problema, primero que nada explico las tablas que eh agregado..
Dentro de mi base de datos tienda un cliente puede tener una **cuenta**, pero existe al menos en mi país dos tipos de **clientes** estos son, (**Personas naturales** y **personas juridicas**). Bueno una persona natural es cualquiera y una institución  o algo por el estilo vienen a ser las jurídicas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta la breve introducción paso a explicar cual es la situación.

Quiero registrar una cuenta a nombre de un Colégio que en este caso viene a ser (**Juridico**), pero todo cliente jurídico tiene un **representante legal** es por eso que relacione **Jurídico** con la tabla **persona_natural** el cual contiene los atributos de una persona y evitar así tener que agregar los atributos nombres,apellidos etc del representante legal. Hasta ahí almenos para mi parece estar bien, pero ahora el gran problema *¡Hacer la factura a nombre de la institución!*. Según mi modelo no se puede por que tengo relacionado solo al cliente con la factura y Se supone que la factura debe salir a nombre de la institución y no del representante legal, estoy en la duda de si agregarle a mi tabla factura los atributos (Nombre, Ruc_o_cedula) para que al momento de hacer la factura obtener los datos de la institución a través del  representante legal e insertarlo en la tabla factura, no se si esto sea lo correcto.

Bueno amigos ese es el problema, a todo esto quiero agregar que antes de hacer la pregunta en el foro acudí a un ex profesor de informática del colegio en el cual estudie para ver que opinaba al respecto, el  me propuso que en ves de segmentar tanto a la entidad cliente simplemente le cargara todos los atributos algo asi..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces en esa tabla si es un **cliente natural** lo registro normalmente, pero si es un **jurídico** en el atributo **nombre** ingresar el nombre de la institución, en el **ruc_o_cedula** ingresar el RUC, etc etc.. quedando atributos en blanco como los apellidos...... esa fue la solución que me propuso, pero pienso que esta mal por que ya estaría violando las reglas de normalización si dejo atributos en blanco ... espero tengan paciencia y puedan ayudarme un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te diría que el problema principal que te está trancando es el diseño de la tabla `cliente`, en particular su clave primaria `idpersona`. Este diseño te impide definir que un cliente pueda ser una *persona jurídica*. De hecho, se puede ver en tu modelo que no hay línea entre la tabla `cliente` y la tabla `juridico`. Eso no es correcto.

Lo que necesitas hacer es asignarle una clave primaria diferente a la tabla `cliente` que simplemente sirva para identificar un registro en la tabla `cliente`. Y luego aparte, defines 2 columnas en la misma tabla, `idpersona` y `idjuridico` con claves foráneas a sus tablas respectivas (`persona_natural` y `juridico`). La idea es que para cada registro en la tabla `cliente`, le asignas valor a uno de los 2 campos (`idpersona` o `idjuridico`) para establecer que tipo de cliente es.

Ejemplo:

```
create table cliente (
  idcliente int auto_increment not null primary key,
  idpersona int unique,
  idjuridico int unique,
  ultima_compra date,
  estado varchar(45),
  constraint persona_fk foreign key (idpersona) references persona_natural(idpersona),
  constraint juridico_fk foreign key (idjuridico) references juridico(idjuridico)
);
```

De ser necesario, puedes definir un trigger para garantizar que solo puedes tener un valor sea en `idpersona` o `idjuridico` a la vez. Normalmente, esto se hace con un `check constraint`, pero no funcionan con MySQL.

Siendo que hay cierta complejidad en hacer una consulta a la tabla `cliente` teniendo que juntar de forma condicional con las demás tablas, vale la pena esconder esa complejidad dentro de una vista. Algo como esto:

```
create view vw_cliente as
select case when p.idpersona is not null then 'PERSONA' else 'JURIDICO' end as tipo_cliente,
       c.ultima_compra,
       c.estado,
       p.*,
       j.*
  from cliente c
  left join persona_natural p
    on p.idpersona = c.idpersona
  left join (select j.idjuridico,
                    j.razon_social,
                    j.ruc,
                    j.tipo_entidad,
                    j.correo_electronico,
                    p.numero as numero_representante_legal,
                    p.cedula as cedula_representante_legal,
                    p.direccion as direccion_representate_legal
               from juridico j
               join persona_natural p
                 on j.idrepresentante_legal = p.idpersona) j
    on j.idjuridico = c.idjuridico;
```

Otro punto, es que la tabla `cuenta` debería tener un campo `idcliente` en vez de `cliente_idpersona` (lo mismo para la tabla `factura`). Es mas, no creo que la tabla `cuenta` deba tener un campo `tipo_cliente`. Si acaso, tal vez lo puedes mover a la tabla `cliente`, y te puede servir como discriminador, pero no es estrictamente necesario, sobre todo si usas la vista que te propuse más arriba que ya incluye un discriminador.

Aquí te dejo un script de ensayo para demostrar cómo pudieras poner en práctica los puntos mencionados:

```
drop view if exists vw_cliente;
drop table if exists cliente;
drop table if exists juridico;
drop table if exists persona_natural;
drop procedure if exists cliente_check;

create table persona_natural (
  idpersona int auto_increment not null primary key,
  numero varchar(45),
  cedula int,
  direccion varchar(45)
);

create table juridico (
  idjuridico int auto_increment not null primary key,
  razon_social varchar(45),
  ruc varchar(45),
  tipo_entidad varchar(45),
  correo_electronico varchar(45),
  idrepresentante_legal int not null,
  constraint representate_legal_fk foreign key (idrepresentante_legal) references persona_natural(idpersona)
);

create table cliente (
  idcliente int auto_increment not null primary key,
  idpersona int unique,
  idjuridico int unique,
  ultima_compra date,
  estado varchar(45),
  constraint persona_fk foreign key (idpersona) references persona_natural(idpersona),
  constraint juridico_fk foreign key (idjuridico) references juridico(idjuridico)
);

delimiter $$
create procedure cliente_check(in idpersona int, in idjuridico int)
begin
  if (idpersona is null and idjuridico is null) or (idpersona is not null and idjuridico is not null) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Hay que asignar un valor sea a idpersona o idjuridico.';
  end if;
end
$$

create trigger cliente_insert_trigger
before insert on cliente
for each row
begin
  call cliente_check(new.idpersona, new.idjuridico);
end
$$

create trigger cliente_update_trigger
before update on cliente
for each row
begin
  call cliente_check(new.idpersona, new.idjuridico);
end
$$
delimiter ;

create view vw_cliente as
select case when p.idpersona is not null then 'PERSONA' else 'JURIDICO' end as tipo_cliente,
       c.ultima_compra,
       c.estado,
       p.*,
       j.*
  from cliente c
  left join persona_natural p
    on p.idpersona = c.idpersona
  left join (select j.idjuridico,
                    j.razon_social,
                    j.ruc,
                    j.tipo_entidad,
                    j.correo_electronico,
                    p.numero as numero_representante_legal,
                    p.cedula as cedula_representante_legal,
                    p.direccion as direccion_representate_legal
               from juridico j
               join persona_natural p
                 on j.idrepresentante_legal = p.idpersona) j
    on j.idjuridico = c.idjuridico;

-- Ejemplo de cliente que es una persona natural.
insert into persona_natural (numero, cedula, direccion) values ('11223344', 123456789, '100 Main St.');
insert into cliente (idpersona, ultima_compra, estado) values (last_insert_id(), '2016-11-01', 'ACTIVO');

-- Ejemplo de cliente que es una persona jurídica.
insert into persona_natural (numero, cedula, direccion) values ('55667788', 987654321, '200 Legal St.');
insert into juridico (razon_social, correo_electronico, idrepresentante_legal) values ('Microsoft', 'microsoft@gmail.com', last_insert_id());
insert into cliente (idjuridico, ultima_compra, estado) values (last_insert_id(), '2016-11-02', 'ACTIVO');

select * from vw_cliente;

drop view if exists vw_cliente;
drop table cliente;
drop table juridico;
drop table persona_natural;
drop procedure cliente_check;
```

Comment: amigo muchísimas gracias justo lo que necesitaba gracias por su tiempo

Comment: amigo otra pregunta en cuanto a los joins de la **vw_cliente**.. entiendo que el primer join **from cliente c
  left join persona_natural p** trae todos los clientes con sus respectivas coincidencias en la tabla persona_natural(cliente es la tabla de la izquierda), hasta ahí todo bien, pero que pasa con el segundo join.. **left join (select j.idjuridico**  con este segundo join se supone que aun sigue partiendo desde la tabla cliente???, o es que ya viene a tomar como referencia a la tabla **persona_natural** del primer join como la tabla de la izquierda ?? :o

Comment: Ni uno ni otro. La "tabla" a la izquierda es el resultado del join entre `cliente` y `persona_natural`. De modo que es una combinación de ambas tablas que sirve de referencia para el tercer join.

Answer (score 3):

Aclaremos los conceptos:

Toda FACTURA se emite a nombre de un CLIENTE. El CLIENTE puede ser una PERSONA NATURAL o una PERSONA JURIDICA.  Además toda PERSONA JURIDICA tiene asociado un REPRESENTANTE LEGAL, que es una PERSONA NATURAL.

En un diseño de objetos, lo más natural parece crear una abstracción que englobe a ambos tipos de persona: digamos PERSONA (abstracta), de los cuales PERSONA NATURAL y PERSONA JURIDICA son descendientes.

Ahora bien, hay (por lo menos) [tres maneras](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance) de implementar [herencia en bases de datos relacionales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386652/techniques-for-database-inheritance) y cada cual tiene sus desventajas.

Lo más simple en este caso (y en la mayoría) me parece que es la estrategia *"**una sola tabla**  para toda la jerarquía"*, lo que equivaldría a tener una única tabla `persona`  con todos los campos necesarios para ambos tipos concretos, más una columna discriminadora (`tipo_persona`) que me indica si es PERSONA JURIDICA o PERSONA NATURAL. No es del todo elegante/eficiente/normalizado (hay campos que estarán en blanco, debo permitir NULLs), pero la ventaja es la simplicidad en las consultas y modificaciones.

No es muy diferente a lo que te propusieron en ese foro, pero me parece preferible que esta abstracción NO esté implementada en la tabla `cliente`, porque el concepto de personas jurídicas y naturales es más amplio, y puede potencialmente necesitarse para otras "personas" que no sean clientes (ejemplo: proveeedores). En la tabla `cliente` sólo tendría una referencia a `persona`. Además, el campo `persona.representante_legal` (solo usado si `tipo` corresponde a PERSONA JURIDICA) referenciaría a otro registro de  la misma tabla `persona` (pero esta vez debería corresponder a una PERSONA NATURAL).

Si te resulta cómodo, puedes definir una vista (digamos: `cliente_con_nombre`)
que tenga la lógica para extraer el nombre a usar en impresion de facturas.

Por si te interesa (y para aprender), te explico las otras implementaciones alternativas:

- **Una tabla por cada clase concreta**  Tengo dos tablas para los dos tipos de persona (como en tu diseño original), y en la tabla `cliente` tengo dos referencias `cliente.id_persona_natural` y `cliente.id_persona_juridica` (una y solo una será NULL). Desventaja: no es del todo normalizado, la consulta es un poco más complicada, y debo repetir todo si tengo que referencia a "persona" (genérica) en otra tabla.
- **Una tabla por clase concreta, con discriminador** (variante de la anterior). En lugar de dos referencias tengo una sola   `cliente.id_persona` más una columna discriminadora `cliente.tipo_persona` que me dice si es juridica o natural. Desventajas: la referencia puede apuntar a tablas distintas, lo cual es poco ortodoxo, y me impide usar integridad referencial; las consultas son aún más complicadas
- **Una tabla por cada clase, incluyendo abstracta**. Agrego una tabla `persona` que aparte del PK solo tiene campos comunes (ninguno en este caso?); las tablas `persona_juridica` y `persona_natural` agregan una columna que referencia a la `persona` "padre". Cada registro de `persona` tiene un y solo un registro (juridico o natural) que apunta a él. La tabla `cliente` solo tiene una referencia a `persona.id`. Desventaja: aunque es el más normalizado, también es el más complicado para hacer consultas y modificaciones.

Agrego que estas alternativas (y sobre todo la última) son más atractivas cuando la cantidad de clases concretas es grande, o puede aumentar en el futuro. No parece ser el caso aquí, lo cual sería motivo para preferir la solución "todo en una sola tabla".

Comment: amigo como esta muchas gracias por la explicación me ayudo a buscar mas sobre el tema y encontré un video que explica justamente sobre la especialización y generalización en base de datos, adjunto el link esperando que le sirva a alguien mas. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrVNqvm7rAM